# How do I sum a a group of columns with a particular label / column combination?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this sheet that contains an 11x11 matrix of values for each of several values in column A.

So there are dozens of 11X11 values. I want to get a sum for just a subset of each matrix.

For example see the range of values highlighted in yellow in the example sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OrrEhlJzz6yiZNtsbxdF0cQt1Tsiy70ID9xNNDAp6uE/edit?usp=sharing

To be clear highlighting has nothing to do with it, just to illustrate an example subset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went to your spreadsheet and put the answers into B30 and B31

You want B30 to be the sum of cells

```
J10 K10 L10
J11 K11 L11
J12 K12 L12
```

You just have to identify the range, in this case (J10:L12)

so the formula is

```
=SUM(J10:L12)
```

likewise for the second highlighted matrix

```
=SUM(J21:L23)
```